# Exporting Charts from excel stopped working, VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, charts

For my program, I needed to create a chart in an Excel sheet, then export this chart to .a gif image, and then inserting this image onto my form. In principle, everything works, but yesterday, when I was playing with the form, the Runtime error '-2147467259 (80004005) flew out': "Method 'Export' of Object '_Chart' Failed"

The code where the error occurs:

```
    Sub exportAndLoadDiagram(uf As EarthForm)
        
        Dim CurrentFileName As String
        CurrentFileName = Workbooks("MyProject.xlsm").Path & "/current.gif"
         
        Dim MyChart As Chart
        Set MyChart = Workbooks("MyProject.xlsm").Worksheets("Diagram").ChartObjects("EarthOnPicketDiagram").Chart
        'the error is here
        MyChart.Export CurrentFileName, "GIF"
         
        uf.Image_earthOnPicket.Picture = LoadPicture(CurrentFileName)

         
      
        Workbooks("MyProject.xlsm").Worksheets("Diagram").Shapes("EarthOnPicketDiagram").Delete
    End Sub
```

And the most interesting thing is that this error does not always happen. Sometimes it can happen, and sometimes it doesn't. Having checked on the Internet, I saw that people have had such an error since 2003+. But I didn't find a sensible solution. Maybe it doesn't exist.. Maybe there is a solution? Or can someone tell me what alternative way you can export a diagram to a form?

Nothing I've tried has helped

Answer (score 0):

I think the prime candidate for the problem, especially as it is intermittent, is that the file path you are saving to is not correctly formed ... my thought here is that the Workbook is saved somewhere other than on your local device eg it is saved on OneDrive, Sharepoint or similar. You can test the file path by adding the line `Debug.Print CurrentFileName` just after you set the path to this variable and see what it prints to the Immediate window.

A solution would be to save the GIF to your temp folder instead of in the same folder as your Workbook, for which you would replace the line that sets `CurrentFileName` with

```
CurrentFileName = Environ$("temp") & "/current.gif"
```

Bonus tip: assuming you are running your code from within the 'MyProject.xlsm' Workbook, you can replace the usages of `Workbooks("MyProject.xlsm")` with `ThisWorkbook` ... the benefits are cleaner code plus, if you change its name, you don't have to change your code to match.